# How to update a salesforce Mobile SDK app developed in swift

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, salesforce-mobile-sdk

I have an old project integrated salesforce Mobile SDK (version 4.3.1), which is working fine on Xcode 8.1.
Now I want to update to make it working on Xcode 13 (or Xcode 10.1).
When I'm updating pods it is throwing more than 500 errors. Any help or link which can help me.

NOTE: Can not make this project from scratch, since it has a lot of functionalities.

Comment: Swift has evolved. In Xcode 8.1, it was Swift 3.1. You could update little by little using the Wizards with each version of XCode that updates the Swift version. It's a long task. Or do it yourself. And in the same time, update SalesForce SDK to the correct version. In any case, it's a long task.

Comment: Swift issues can be resolved but I'm getting errors in salesforce mobile SDK.